# Why can't I cast generic type to inheriting type?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, inheritance, polymorphism

I have some method with the following definition;

```
 public void SomeMethod<T>() where T : BaseClass, new()
 {
      InheritedClass instance = (InheritedClass)instanceOfT; //won't compile
 }
```

Why is that cast not allowed? How can you get around this? I have about 200 lines of code which is all suited for generics except I need a one LINQ query for each of the inheriting classes (there are 3). I was trying to do a `typeof` check, then follow that with a cast, then execute the appropriate query but the compiler won't let me do the cast... Given I just checked to ensure that `T` is in fact an instance of type `InheritedClass` there is no way it would fail, why won't the compiler let me do it?

Comment: How is `instanceOfT` defined?

Comment: @user7116 One would assume it's an instance of type `T`.  Beyond that, we don't really need to know.

Comment: @user7116 it's returned from a deserializer that is also generic, something like; `T instanceOfT = JsonValidator.Deserialize<T>(jsonString);`

Comment: -1 Do not try to avoid compiler messages, try to think first.

Comment: This smells like an abuse of generics. If the code inside the generic method needs to know what T is then it is not *generic*.  If you want a method that always takes an `InheritedClass` as an argument, *write one*.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal: Read about covariance and contravariance and generic interfaces, use interfaces, not classes. contravariance can help you at compile time. your question related to the fact that compiler reasonbly decnlines your guess about type inference, because in such situation type inference algotithm reasonably thinks of nonsense or mispelling in code

Comment: @EricLippert yeah the compiler adequately deterred me from moving forward with this type of implementation. The reason I wanted to use it is because I thought there could be 9 lines of type specific code in what will be about a 200 line method. Instead I'll just make 3 different methods and use more conventional methods to reduce duplication as much as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cast the variable to `object` and then back down to do this.  As it is the compiler believes that there is no possible way that the cast could succeed, but it doesn't ever apply that check to variables of type `object`.

```
InheritedClass instance = (InheritedClass)(object)instanceOfT;
```

Comment: +1 `InheritedClass instance = instanceOfT as InheritedClass` works too.

Comment: -1 This is wrong way to solve an abstraction problem. Errorneous. Violates the rules. You just need to use interfaces. 54.4k... omg

Comment: @ArturMustafin It depends on the situation.  You shouldn't be relying on it a lot, but there are circumstances in which it's viable.  A good example is LINQ.  A good many of the methods try to cast the type to `ICollection` and do optimizations if it's possible, and then do less efficient options if they aren't.

Comment: 1.2k speaking as if he wrote the C# compiler and defines best practices... omg

Comment: @evanmcdonnal He is right that this is very much a sign of code smell, and based on your comments after I posted my answer this *isn't* an appropriate use of generics/casting and you're *not* using the right approach.  The user's rep isn't really relevant here.

Answer (score 1):

Because the actual instanceOfT's type (let's call it `InheritedClassB`) may not be related to `InheritedClass`.

> Given I just checked to ensure that T is in fact an instance of type InheritedClass

Actually, you're only checking that T extends BaseClass.

**Edit:** This looks like a code smell.. Can't you let the concrete class handle this method? So each concrete class would have its own implementation, and know how to perform `SomeMethod`.

Comment: No, my check is `if (typeof(T) == typeof(InheritedClass))`. The method will always be called with an inherited class. The base class type constraint is only there to limit the function to being used with the inheriting classes.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal Then why not just constrain the type to `InheritingClass` if it *must* be used with objects of that type?

Comment: @Servy my guess is it actually looks a bit like `if (typeof(T) == typeof(InheritedClassA)) { } else if (typeof(T) == typeof(InheritedClassB)) { } else etc.`

Comment: @Servy I thought it would be simpler to have the constraint placed on the base class rather than having a type constraint for each of the inheriting classes. I don't think anyone will be instantiating the base class so it's not really an issue but I'm going away from this method anyways because I think the code duplication is less bad then the nonsense required to make it generic.

Comment: Sounds like you should just have N overloads of the method then, rather than a generic method checking against N types.

Comment: @p.s.w.g that is correct. There would be a little structure like that. The only issue is each of the classes has a list with a different type and I need to do a little projection with LINQ. I can't access that collection in a generic manner. I could potentially change the name, and move into the base class but that would be a pain too because they're named to match the json.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal If you want the same thing from all of the objects then just have them implement an interface the exposes a method that gives you what you need.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal Generics should be applied when the same solution will work for *any* sub-type the user might provide. If you have to apply special logic for each sub-type, then you're probably better off just using overloads.

Comment: @p.s.w.g that's what I'm doing now. I was just wondering what issue there is with the cast. The compiler should be able to see that the cast will never fail.